# how to install Emacs Prelude system-wide on windows/MinGW?

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I am trying to install emacs prelude into emacs. The only thing I found after googling is [this page](http://problemateek.blogspot.com/2012/07/installing-emacs-prelude-in-windows-7.html), which tells me to clone prelude into

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d
```

But I need to have prelude in the emacs system folder because I need to make my emacs folder a zip file and usable on other machines.

What I tried so far (unsuccessfully) are:

```
1. Download emacs 24.5.1 from gnu ftp site, and decompress to c:\emacs

2. git clone git://github.com/bbatsov/prelude.git

3. mv prelude/ /c/emacs/site-lisp
```

I thought step 3 should populate the emacs system-wide startup folder `site-lisp`, and allow prelude to load on emacs startup. But it didn't happen. I loaded a Haskell `.hs` file into emacs, and the Haskell mode isn't automatically activated as the prelude documentation suggests.

Can some one please explain how to correctly install prelude into emacs system-wide?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've "populated" the Emacs `site-lisp` folder in the sense that you've moved the `prelude` directory in full to `site-lisp`. While this would -- in conjunction with `require`-ing accordingly in your configurations -- be sufficient for "installing" Emacs packages, Prelude is not an Emacs "package" in the strictest sense of that word. Rather, Prelude can be thought of as a pre-defined set of configuration files, and *this* is why Prelude is generally cloned either directly into `.emacs.d` or symlinked to from there; it is not a package to `require`, and therefore does not belong in `site-lisp`.

The good news is that this makes your goal of making Emacs + Prelude usable on other machines relatively simple to solve with, say, a Bash script that:

1. Installs `emacs` in the corresponding manner for the current OS/distro/etc.;
2. `git clone git://github.com/bbatsov/prelude.git path/to/local/repo`
3. `ln -s path/to/local/repo ~/.emacs.d`
4. `cd ~/.emacs.d`

Note that the above is essentially the "manual" installation instructions provided at [the Prelude website](http://batsov.com/prelude/).

To make Emacs "portable" across different machines, the general consensus seems to be that it's a better idea to write your configurations in a way that allows them to be flexible and easily portable across machines, rather than bundle up a distribution of the Emacs executable itself.